# Access tomcat application directories in jenkins server in openshift

Tags: openshift

I have 2 applications in my openshift account under the same domain, one tomcat application and another jenkins server. In my jenkins job i want to copy some files into directories of tomcat using linux commands. but I am not able to access those directories from jenkins. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you have tried, and what errors you got, along with what type of files you are trying to copy from jenkins to your tomcat server?

Comment: I am just trying to copy the war file using shell script from jenkins, like:cp *.war /var/lib/openshift/{openshift-app-ssh}/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps. but since both jenkins and tomcat have different home directories it is not possible. I guess i can transfer the war over ssh

Comment: They do not share a filesystem, so you would have to use scp.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins runs on it's own gear, it and your tomcat gear do not share a filesystem, so you can not just "cp" the files into place.  Your best bet would be to either have the files copied over using SCP, or make sure those files you need are present in the git repository and they will be published to your tomcat gear.